# setPropertiesToFetch doesn't work as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I want a list of unique contacts that I've stored with core data.

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setEntity:entityDescription];
        
        
        NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entityDescription propertiesByName];
        
        [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"contactID"]]];
        [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
        
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSMutableArray *retValue = [[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

The result is always the same with or without the `setPropertiesToFetch`, so I guess there is something wrong with it, but I can't figure out what it is.
Can someone help me?

Comment: I've got the same problem, did you manage to overcome it?

Comment: no.. i'm still stuck on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set your fetch result type to `NSDictionaryResultType`? The documentation says `setPropertiesToFetch:` only works when result type == `NSDictionaryResultType`

.n

Comment: Also, the results will be returned as NSManagedObjectID in the returned dictionaries' keys, which it a bit of a pain.